# Permission Denial: starting intent (React Native)

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to create 2 activity aliases to trigger a icon change event inside React-Native.
I am trying to run my app,but i get an error inside AndroidManifest.xml. Does anybody know the answer?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.projectname">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/checked"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />

        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.example.MainActivitychecked"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/checked"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
            
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity-alias
            android:name="com.example.MainActivitycancel"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/cancel"
            android:targetActivity=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity-alias>

        <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the error (I don't know what causes it..)

```
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.projectname/.MainActivity }

Exception occurred while executing: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.projectnam/.MainActivity } 
from null (pid=8962, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10152
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.projectname/.MainActivity } from null (pid=8962, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10152
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a mistake that caused this error. I was doing this:

```
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/checked"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

But i had to do this:

```
    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/checked"
        android:allowBackup="false"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
 />
```

Basically i had to put android:exported="true" inside  instead of >application> . Now the issue is solved.